# Convert List to Dictionary using python

Tags: list, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary

I have a List in python as Below:

```
lst = [
    [u'TimeStampUTC', u'Turbine', u'Power'], 
    [20150716143000.0, u'RENDG-01', 81], 
    [20150716143000.0, u'RENDG-02', 82], 
    [20150716143000.0, u'RENDG-03', 83], 
    [20150716143000.0, u'RENDG-04', 84], 
    [20150716143000.0, u'RENDG-05', 85]
]
```

I need to convert it to Dictionary as follows:

```
dictionary = {
    'TimeStampUTC' : [20150716143000, 20150716143000, 20150716143000, 20150716143000, 20150716143000], 
    'Turbine': ['RENDG-01', 'RENDG-02', 'RENDG-03', 'RENDG-04', 'RENDG-05'], 
    'Power': [81, 82, 83, 84, 85]
}
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = dict(zip(lst[0], zip(*lst[1:])))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zac.. The Snippet is working fine.

Comment: Hey can we remove character 'u' from u'RENDG-03' and push it dictionary value as 'RENDG-03'.

Comment: Character 'u' indicates that it is an unicode object. You can encode it in whatever character set you need using `x.encode(charset)` (e.g. `x.encode('utf8')`)

Answer (score 0):

Without using zip (which is fancy), you can create the list using

```
# create empty dictionary
d = {}
# iterate through the keys in the first entry of the list
for c,key in enumerate(lst[0]):
    # add to the dictionary using the key from the
    # first row and the c-th column of every other row
    d[str(key)] = [x[c] for x in lst[1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you redimp. The snippet which was suggested by Zac was taking keys in Tuple but your snippet has lead me into list of values for i was looking. This was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Hey can we remove character 'u' from u'RENDG-03' and push it dictionary value as 'RENDG-03'.

Comment: The 'u' is an indicator for a unicode string. For correct handling of unicode strings see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html. Since you get ints and floats in you list, better cast not everything. For this example use: `d['Turbine'] = [str(x) for x in d['Turbine']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
my_dict={}
for ind,key in enumerate(lst[0]):
    my_dict[key]=[lst[i][ind] for i in range(1,len(lst))]
```